# imagemagick "convert" command different outputs

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a 8 page pdf to 8 separate pbm files, using imagemagick. When I do `convert test.pdf test.jpg`, 8 jpg files (test-0.jpg, test-1.jpg ..) are created, but when I use the command `convert test.pdf test.pbm` only 1 pbm file (test.pbm) is created. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert test.pdf out-%0d.pbm
```

This will give you out-0.pbm out-1.pbm...  I don't know why imagemagick does this automatically for jpg but not for pbm..  If you want to pad the number to be 000-999 then add a "3" in front of the d.

Example:

```
convert test.pdf out-%03d.pbm
```